# Try to pik information with XPath

Tags: xml, xpath

Before all, thanks for your time.

I want to pick information from some webs and I have problems with any expressions like that.

```
           <a class="xxxxx">
           <br>
            Hi
           <br>
           <span class="hpn">City</span>
           : Barcelona
           <br>
           <span class="hpn">color</span>
           : Blue
           <br>
           <span class="hpn">Price</span>
           : 50
           <br>
```

I want pick the information of city color and price with the results Barcelona, Blue, 50

Im waiting your answers!

Comment: We're waiting for you to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Any reason for using Xpath ? Why not use regex to extract information. Above example is actually HTML, not XML ?

Answer (score 2):

In the absence of any other info including your knowledge of Xpath, I would direct you to an [Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/).

Answer (score 0):

Since above text is HTML not XML (although you tagged it as XML), I don't think you can get it to work as-is. Above extract can not be interpreted as a well-formed XML, unless you add the closing tags for the `<a>` tag (Suppose you just forgot to copy that), but also all `<br>` tags need to be self-closing `<br/>` in order to get this parsed. Since I don't know in what language you are going to try this (not specified), perhaps your parser will work fine but still I fear for the outcome of the XPath query. But assuming it will work, a query like

```
//a[@class='xxxxx']/span[text()='City']/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

will return ': Barcelona'  (you can substring it to remove the ': ' part)

or

```
//a[@class='xxxxx']/span/following-sibling::text()[1]
```

will return the first siblings after each span class